# iPython notebook not loading: too much output

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have an iPython notebook file which is not loading, presumably because there is too much output in the file (thousands of lines of results printed, old computer).

I can edit the file with notepad without problems, but copying and then cleaning the code from there cell by cell is very time-consuming.

Is there a way to recover the code differently, or to ask iPython notebook to only load the code and not print all the past outputs when opening the file?

Comment: Does this help you? https://gist.github.com/minrk/6176788#file-nbstripout. All credits go to minrk of course :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is an output removal script I found on [Github](https://gist.github.com/minrk/3719849). Credits to the author.

```
      import sys
      import io
      from IPython.nbformat import current


      def remove_outputs(nb):
          for ws in nb.worksheets:
              for cell in ws.cells:
                  if cell.cell_type == 'code':
                      cell.outputs = []`


      if __name__ == '__main__':
          fname = sys.argv[1]
          with io.open(fname, 'r') as f:
              nb = current.read(f, 'json')
              remove_outputs(nb)
              print current.writes(nb, 'json')
```